# Почему не работает конструктор. JS функции

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает данный кусПок код? Алерт не выводит ни `TEST1`, ни `TEST2`:

```
var cards = document.body.getElementsByClassName('cards');

function Animati(options){
     var elem = options.elem;
    var currentCount = 1;
    var img = null;



    elem.onmousedown = function(){
        return false;
    };

    elem.onclick = function(event){
        alert('TEST1')
        go();
    };

    function go(){
        if (img){
            alert('TEST2');
           currentCount++;
           img = this.querySelector('.card_img');
           img.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
                setTimeout(function(){
                    img.style.animationPlayState = '';
                    img.style.animationIterationCount = currentCount;
                }, 1000);
        }
    };

    this.go = go;
}



var ani = [];


for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    var ani = new Animati({
        elem: cards[i] 
    });  
}
```

Хотя этот код работает:

```
var animationCard = function(event){
currentCount++;
var img = this.querySelector('.card_img');
img.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
setTimeout(function(){
                img.style.animationPlayState = '';
                img.style.animationIterationCount = currentCount;
            }, 1000);
```

}

```
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    cards[i].onclick = throttle(animationCard);
    cards[i].onmouseover = throttle(animationCard);
}
```

(по клику на карточку Cards, картинка img внутри нее анимируется)

Comment: Через консоль в хроме проверь присвоился ли onclick

Comment: @EliotAlderson  , присволся onclick из другого конструктора, который раскрывает текст в этих карточках. А почему этот не присваивается?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо прямого присвоения использовать addEventListener

Comment: Дорогой  @DmitryFilippov. Если Вы хотите, чтобы на Ваши вопросы продолжали отвечать, отмечайте правильные/принятые ответы знаком "галочка" слева от них.